# 'long' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Tags: python, django

I don't know what is wrong in this code; previously it was working fine but after a database migration (sqlite3 to MySQL) it is no longer working. (I am using MySQL).

Traceback:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

code:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()            
    data = cursor.execute(query)
    data_list = data.fetchall()
    return redirect("http://www.example.com?code=123" , code=302)
    result_count = len(data_list)           
    if result_count==0:
        return HttpResponse('<script type="text/javascript"> alert ("try again"); window.location.href = "/reports/custom/";</script>')
    data_desc = data.description

    j=0
    """
        prepare first response  
    """
    now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S')            
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=hiv_report_%s.csv' % now         
    writer = csv.writer(response)

    headers = []
    tab_no = 0
    for i in data_desc:
        #ws.write(0, j, (i[0].replace('_', ' ')).upper())                
        if i[0] == 'id':
            table_name = tab_order[tab_no]
            tab_no = tab_no +1

        headers.append((table_name+ " | " +i[0].replace('_', ' ')).upper())   

    writer.writerow(headers)
    """
        fill data into csv cells
    """            
    for value in data_list:
        k=0
        no_record_check=1                
        row = []
        for val in value:
            #ws.write(j, k, val)
            row.append(val)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MySQLdb.cursor.execute(query)` returns an integer with the number of returned rows. Number objects don't have `fetchall` method. You need to call `fetchall` method on a `cursor`:

```
data_list = cursor.fetchall()
```

To quote [Python DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

```
.execute(operation [, parameters])
Prepare and execute a database operation (query or command).
[...]
Return values are not defined.
```

As Martijn said in the comment `sqlite3.cursor.execute` returns cursor.
Since return value of `cursor.execute` is not defined by DB API `MySQLdb.cursor.execute` can return anything (the library writers chose to return a number of rows).

This means that the portable way of working with Python DB API is to ignore the return value of `cursor.execute`.

Comment: Exactly, and the `sqlite3` `cursor.execute()` call just returns the cursor, which is why it used to work before.

Comment: Thanks but now i am getting : 

'long' object has no attribute 'description'

Comment: @user3269734, you need to use the `cursor` object instead of `data`. So `data.description` should be `cursor.description`.